# Flow object with unknown number of fields

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How do I define the type of an object that I know has two fields for sure: id and name, and an unknown other number of fields which names follow the pattern `string_string`.

So, for example, an object I would have is:

{id: '1', name: 'john', 'fa2_oh': 'value'}

I know how to define the type if the object just had `id` and `name`:

`{ id: string, name: string }`

But how do I define the other potential keys?

Comment: You can add an indexer property, but you won't be able to restrict the keys to specific pattern

Answer (score 1):

As Aleksey said, you can add an indexer property, but it's not possible to specify a *pattern* of strings.

```
type BaseT = { a: string, b: number, [string]: boolean }
const foo: BaseT = { a: 'a', b: 1, hello: false }
```

If the pattern is somewhat bounded, you could spell out that type:

```
type KeysT = 'fa_oh1' | 'fa_oh2' | 'bb_aa1' | 'bb_aa2'
type BaseT = { a: string, b: number, [KeysT]: boolean }
const foo: BaseT = { a: 'a', b: 1, hello: false }
```